# Postgresql 8.4 - Limiting window function range

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, postgresql-8.4, window-functions

Is it possible to limit the range over a window function is calculated?.

I'm using PostgreSql 8.4.

An example query:

```
select count(*) over() as TOTAL, id, .... from table limit 100
```

This query returns the 100 top records, its first column displays all the records without taking into account the limit.

The question is, is there a way to also limit the range inside the count?, I mean, if the original query returns a total of 5000, I only need to tell "more than 1000".

edit: the question can be replaced by, does PostgreSql has a way to know if a query has more than "n" results?.

Comment: You could do it with `OVER (ROWS BETWEEN 1000 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)` ... but if you're trying to achieve an efficiency gain / performance boost by doing so, it won't help. What are you trying to achieve by doing this, what's your _goal_, what's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Thanks Craig, I thought so. What I try to do is to simply tell the user there are more than X records, and he is seeing only X.

Comment: Are you really only interested in whether the query `has more than "n" results`? Not how many if there are less?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, good question. Btw, I was thinking removing the count and using, for example, limit 101, if the retrieved records are more than 100 I would show "there are more than 100 records, please apply a filter", and if they are less than 100, simply show "X records retrieved."

Comment: Well, we are using this simple approach in several places. But it neither answers my question nor does it fit *your* question where you have limit 100 and want a count up to 1000. Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry @ErwinBrandstetter for the confusion. I was mixing ideas while I was writing. Currently we use the "count(*) over...query..limit 100" approach, but this wasn't fast enough for us, because the count have to traverse all the results (can be 50k for example), so I was thinking of limiting the count, and showing the user "there are more than N results", but as Craig Ringer said, it won't boost the performance. The last idea is simply remove the count and show the text "there are more than (limit-1) results".

Comment: @leonardorame: Well, it's one of the rare instances where Craig is wrong - as detailed in my answer.

Comment: @CraigRinger: You might be interested ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's actually a clever idea. Why count all the way if you are only interested in first N rows?

I ran a couple of test and [window functions with a custom frame definition](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) were *faster* for big result sets:

```
count(*) OVER (ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1001 FOLLOWING) AS total_max_1001
```

The problem is, you may get a different count for every row, which may or may not be a problem. If you only consider the *first* row, this works just fine.

Either way, for big result sets, a (uncorrelated) subquery was **much faster**, yet:

```sql
SELECT id
     ,(SELECT count(*)::int
       FROM  (SELECT FROM tbl WHERE ... LIMIT  1001) x  -- repeat conditions
      ) AS total_max_1001
FROM   tbl
WHERE  ...
LIMIT  100;
```

Tests were in Postgres 9.1. I expect similar results for all versions since 8.4, up to 9.3.

Gives you an exact full count up to 1001 (which may be read as "more than 1000"), but does not count any further. Also works great with indexes. I am going to tune a couple of my own queries with this ...

Comment: I marked this as the correct answer, because it solves my original question, although I probably won't use it, because *I think* it doesn't improve the performance significantly, I must test both cases.

Comment: @leonardorame: I *know* it can improve performance because I ran extensive tests before posting and it works for me. It depends on a number of factors, not least on indexes and your actual `WHERE` conditions. But I saw massive improvements in various scenarios.

Comment: Huh, nicely done. I'm quite surprised by that result.